Junit tests fail intermittently in pipeline since gradle upgrade
We are getting some intermittent failures in Junit test cases in our pipeline. It is hard to figure out since it works on re-runs.
The error to be specific is:
java.lang.IllegalStateException at DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98
        Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException at InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:160
            Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at XMLObjectProviderRegistrySupport.java:107

The code at this place probably is:
public static XMLObjectBuilderFactory getBuilderFactory() {
    return ((XMLObjectProviderRegistry)ConfigurationService.get(XMLObjectProviderRegistry.class)).getBuilderFactory();
}

We use this class in our junits as below:
XMLObjectProviderRegistrySupport.getParserPool()

Not sure why this has started failing since upgrade from Gradle 7.x to 8.x
Gradle version: 8.4
OpenSaml version: 4.0.1
Spring boot version: 2.7.18
Spring framework: 5.3.x
Am I missing something here ?
UPDATE:
I have realized, the issue with XMLObjectProviderRegistrySupport is not the only problem.
In general the junit tests have become flaky (fail intermittently) since upgrade from gradle 7.2 to 7.6.x

Please add full stacktraces, include which library versions you are using and show a test that is failing. The stacktrace indicates Spring usage (Spring or Spring Boot) and depending on the version the Gradle version might not be supported.

What is ConfigurationService? I suspect get returns null.

@M.Deinum
Spring boot version: 2.7.18
Spring framework: 5.3.x
This is the full stack trace. The junits do not print much in the pipeline.
Thanks!
